# how to call a function with parameters that is assigned to a variable in JQuery .each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I pass arguments to a function that is assigned to variable.
For example:

```
var updateDiv = function() {
   var row = this;
   var values = "";
   $('input[type=text],textarea,input[type=radio]:checked,input[type=checkbox]:checked', this).each(function() {
       if ($(this).val()!="" && $(this).val()!=null) {
           if (values!="") values = values + ","+ $(this).val();
           else values +=  $(this).val();
         }
       });
      if (values!="") { 
       if(values.substring(0,1)==",") values = values.substring(1) +"<br>";
       else values = values +"<br>";
      } 
      $('.jist', row).append(values);
}

$('tr:has(input)').each(updateDiv);
$('tr:has(textarea)').each(updateDiv);
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
<td>ai</td><td> <input type="text" name="ai" id="ai"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ana" id="ana" value="N/A"></td>
<td><div class="jist"></div></td>
</tr>
```

I want to pass arguments to `updateDiv` -> `updateDiv("mystring")`;
and I want to use "mystring" in the function this way - >  `$('.'+mystring, row).append(values);`

Comment: Your question is about passing arguments to functions used in each(), and has nothing to do with assignments?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass arguments to the function "updateDiv" used in each(). if I do `$('tr:has(input)').each(updateDiv("mystring"));` and modify my function's last line to `$('.'+mystring, row).append(values);` it's throwing an error: _TypeError: c is undefined_

Comment: No, I meant that you might should edit your question's title

Comment: @Sapphire I strongly suggest you get some [*language basics*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) first. You are passing a reference to a Function instance to the `each()` method, so that `each()` can call that function. The term for this is *callback*. The question is: What value do you want to pass to the referred function? Your function has an empty parameter list, and you are not using `arguments` in the function body. So whatever *this* function is passed, it does exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple and Clean

Not sure how I missed the obvious here.

jQuery

```
var updateDiv = function(divClass) {    
    ...
    $(divClass, row).append(values);
}

$('tr:has(input)').each(function(){ updateDiv('.hist'); });
$('tr:has(textarea)').each(function(){ updateDiv('.something-else'); });
```

.

### Global Variable Method

You could assign global variables with the class name. By defining the variable before each `.each()` the `updateDiv` function uses a different class name.

jQuery

```
var updateDiv = function() {    
    ...
    $(window.divClass, row).append(values);
}

window.divClass = '.hist';
$('tr:has(input)').each(updateDiv);
window.divClass = '.something-else';
$('tr:has(textarea)').each(updateDiv);​
```

.

### HTML5 Data Method

You could assign values as data objects to the elements which are being called. I also cleaned up some of your selectors and jQuery redundancies.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/KWCdn/

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr data-update=".hist">
        <td>AutoI</td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="autoIH_complaint" id="autoIH_complaint"></td>
        <td><input class="NA" type="checkbox" name="autoINA" id="autoINA" value="N/A"></td>
        <td><div class="hist"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
var updateDiv = function() {

    var row = this, values = "";
    $('input:text,textarea,:radio:checked,:checkbox:checked', this).each(function() {
        if (this.value != "" && this.value != null) {
            if (values != "") values = values + "," + this.value;
            else values += this.value;
        }
    });
    if (values != "") {
        if (values.substring(0, 1) == ",") values = values.substring(1) + "<br>";
        else values = values + "<br>";
    }
    $(row.data('update'), row).append(values);
}

$('tr:has(input)').each(updateDiv);
$('tr:has(textarea)').each(updateDiv);​
```

Comment: Please look at the HTML code I added. that's the model I'm using.

Comment: @Sapphire I see the update but no real big change in how it would be implemented. I updated my code here and the fiddle for clarity though.

Comment: It's a huge form so can I achieve this without making any changes to the HTML? Editing each row will take me 2 hrs.

Comment: Done. Not sure how I missed this. Too much jQuerying too little JavaScripting I guess.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass the index into the function, much like jQuery's `.each()` method.

```
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>​
```

This will alert "0" and then "1" for the indexes.

```
var updateDiv = function( index )
{   
    alert( index );
}

$('.test').each(updateDiv);
```

If you pass in strings as parameters, `.each(updateDiv("string1"))` it is evaluates the function first.